# Cardinality of one-sided and mutual authentication (entity-relationship modeling)

Tags: database-design, erd

I would like to model client computers that are identified by servers that validate their computer certificates. I am stuck at the cardinality of the relationship between a client and a server when the client certificate is validated by the server.

The reason I am not satisfied with a one-to-one (1:1) relationship is that there are configuration options that require the server to be identified as well. If I describe the one-sided authentication as a 1:1 relationship, then how do I describe mutual authentication? Should I model two relationships?